# Vue Extension "Volar" is not formatting code inside Script setup

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to make Volar extension to format code in script setup? I'm not using Vetur because it is not compatible enough with vue 3 and its new syntax.

Comment: Are you using CTRL+SHIFT+P and the "Format Document" action in VS Code? It works for me in Volar. If you mean ESLint formatting rules etc. check out https://github.com/sethidden/vue3-eslint-stylelint-demo

Comment: When I made this question, my problem was eslint configuration. I was trying Vue 3 + vite and got a little lost with my configs there. I ended blaming Volar at that time. My bad  Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add volar extensions according to the nuxt3 official document as shown in the link. (https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html)

And add the code below to .vscode/setting.json at the top of the project.

```
"[vue]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
},
```

If it doesn't apply right away,
press the command + shift + p key to run the command window, and then run the  **> Developer: Reload Window command.**